# Session_destroy() retorna erro

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma página, e em partes, uso PHP, mas em uma parte dá um erro no log out.
Segue o erro:

> Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session on line 22.

Segue a linha:

```
if ((!$loginrequired) or ((isset($_SESSION) or !isset($_SESSION) and session_start()) 
    and (isset($_SESSION['lname']) and isset($_SESSION['lpass'])) 
    and isValidLogin($_SESSION['lname'], $_SESSION['lpass']))) {

    header("location:/questions/home");
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['lpass']);
    unset($_SESSION['lname']);
    if (isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

Achei estranho o erro aparecer, se fiz a checagem.
Alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: O `session_start` deve ser a primeira coisa a ser iniciado em seu script, antes de qualquer echo ou saída. O que ele está fazendo dentro do `if` ?

Answer (score 1):

Usa assim:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: Mas isso causaria outro problema, iniciar uma sessão ja iniciada. Editei ali em cima, botei a bloco inteiro.

Comment: o que eu encontrei ate agora você precisa iniciar a session na pagina para depois dar um destroi. Voc~E chegou a testar ao menos ?

Comment: Não testei, você chegou a ver o bloco? em:
if ((!$loginrequired) or ((isset($_SESSION) or !isset($_SESSION) and session_start()) and (isset($_SESSION['lname']) and isset($_SESSION['lpass'])) and isValidLogin($_SESSION['lname'], $_SESSION['lpass'])))

Eu vejo se foi iniciado, se não, inicia a session.

Comment: não cheguei a testar o session_start no if mas pelo que vejo com o pessoal todo aqui usamos da forma inicia e destroi coisas assim direto

Comment: Usei o que você mandou, e como eu disse, deu erro:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: só que ele precisa estar no topo da pagina senão o session_start da esse erro mesmo

Comment: Não faz sentido, do mesmo modo vai dar o erro

Comment: beleza então muita gente esta tendo problema. pois é a solução que funciona. http://www.portugal-a-programar.pt/topic/58548-session-destroy-nao-destroi/

Comment: ou se quiser usar a propria resposta so stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752858/warning-session-destroy acho que fica mais facil

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa. Ja botei o session_start() e da o erro acima.